# Running a python script on a local PC from a web app running at localhost

Tags: python, web-applications

I have made a web app in which I have included a chatbot (using Api.Ai), now I want my chatbot to do the following:

Suppose I ask it to install a particular piece of software, then it should do the same. Using pyautogui and selenium I'm able to do this with a Python script, but the problem is I want my chatbot to run that Python file.

If it cannot then I can convert it into .exe format also. Is there any way by which I can execute the .exe file by clicking on some link on my web app?

Comment: in other words..I want to run a .exe file on client machine via a server

Comment: I'm not sure that this is really possible - there are all kinds of restrictions on things like this that websites are allowed to do, because it's too easy for people to use maliciously. Can you imagine what it would be like to have websites constantly trying to install things on your machine?

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution for this kind of use case. I'm trying to create an app that should be able to run a local script on the user's computer. Currently, my solution is to distribute the app as a desktop app, so that it can run a local script for the user. But I'm looking for an alternative where I don't have to distribute the app's source code. Yeah, I could create a .exe file so that it obfuscate the code, but still having a web app removes distributing the source altogether. But yeah, on the security side, I don't think this is really possible. What are your thoughts?